# Python3 - Urllib & BeautifulSoup4 to Extract Specific Text

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am new to python and I am trying to get a script working alongside with urllib and BeautifulSoup4 to collect the tweets which are streamable via the emojitracker API. It outputs the tweets of a specific emoji as .json files. An example is this link (opens in chrome):
http://emojitracker.com/api/details/1F52B

I can get all the text from the .json, but I only want to get the tweet (which is after "text:"). I had a look around and there was an example to get all the links on the page, using soup.findAll("a",class_="classname").

I used inspect element and found that the tweet i need is stored as: (span class="type-string")tweet goes here(/span). So I tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = "http://emojitracker.com/api/details/1F52B"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"html.parser")
tweets = soup.findAll("span", class_"type-string")

for tweet in tweets:
    print (tweet.string)
```

Running, this it did not print anything. How can I make it so that it only prints out the tweets?

Comment: `soup.findAll("span", class_"type-string")` doesn't look like valid syntax. Are you sure you don't mean `soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'type-string'})` ?

Comment: I tried that too, but still did not print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you provide is not an html page. In fact it's formatted as a json file, so you won't be able to treat it as an HTML page.

As I understand, what you want is to retrieve all of the recent tweets.

In order to do this, we get the response, as already do, and parse the response string and convert it to a Python dictionary using the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library (which does not require installation as it's part of the standard library).

If you want to do this, we can write the following code:

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = "http://emojitracker.com/api/details/1F52B"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
json = json.loads(str(page.read(), 'latin'))

for tweet in json['recent_tweets']:
    print(tweet['text'])
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: That seems like a better way to deal with it, however I am getting an error:

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'.

Whats the reason for this? Is the json formatted properly?